# Should I pick the darker colored wood at the lumber yard?

Tags: softwood

When I compare softwood like douglas fir, I try to pick wood that is straight and doesn't have too many knots.

When I find several pieces of wood, should I then go for the darker colored wood?

I assume the darker colored pieces are more likely to be heartwood and they should be more rot resistant no?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to WSE. Untreated lumber is not 'rot' resistant, and it will little matter whether the wood is new or older.  If your wood will be exposed to water frequently then use pressure treated wood intended for wetter conditions.

Comment: *"I assume the darker colored pieces are more likely to be heartwood and they should be more rot resistant no?"* It's not as clearcut as that unfortunately. There is a lot of misunderstanding about heartwood having greater rot resistance, and from it misleading advice/information on the topic is commonplace online. If you want a clearer picture you need to go to primary sources, so hunt down the PDF of the FPL's cornerstone **Wood As An Engineering Material** for more on this (primarily covering domestic North American woods). [contd]

Comment: But, as @Ashlar says if you really want resistant softwood then it's a safer bet (much safer) to go with pressure-treated wood. If you don't want to use treated (for any reason, no judgement) then you may want to consider primarily looking at building using hardwoods and not softwoods. Although again, it's not as clearcut as hardwoods > softwoods for rot resistance, q.v. the PDF I mention :-)

Comment: OP are you still monitoring your Question?

Answer (score 3):

> I assume the darker colored pieces are more likely to be heartwood and they should be more rot resistant no?

I don't think that's necessarily a valid assumption. As far as I know, heartwood *is* generally darker than sapwood, but if you're picking through the lumber at your local home center and one board is darker than another, it's likely that they're just from two different trees, or one has been lying around longer, or one was on the outside of the bundle when it rained during transport, or something like that.

In any case, any differences in rot resistance related to the color of the wood are likely to be pretty unreliable. If you need rot resistance for whatever you're building, buy material that's actually known to be rot resistant, i.e. either pressure treated lumber, or cypress or other species that are naturally rot resistant.